# How to input value to matrix by user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

How to insert value to matrix by user input?
I've got some code like this.

```
n,m = raw_input().split(' ')
matrix = [[0 for x in range(int(n))] for y in range(int(m))]
```

How it should looks like:

```
user input : 
2 2 #dementions of matrix
1 2 #matrix[1][1] = 1; #matrix[2][1] = 2
3 4 #matrix[2][1] = 3; #matrix[2][2] = 4

output :
1 2 #matrix[1][1] = 1; #matrix[2][1] = 2
3 4 #matrix[2][1] = 3; #matrix[2][2] = 4
```

Comment: and how to calculate a lenght of matrix?

Comment: Do you really want to prevent the user from using commas as separators? Do you really want no prompt at all for each line, not even saying the first input line contains the dimensions and the others are the matrix rows? Do you really want no error checking? Do you really want the matrix to start at `matrix[1][1]` rather than the Python standard `matrix[0][0]`? (Your code is zero-based while your example uses one-based.)

Comment: Yes, i do! It just training task for like in interview in companies, i would like to train by doing this tasks. And i have a problem when i try do it. This task don't need to use commas as separators, becouse on the othes side the test programm will put values in input places. It is a conditions of the task

Comment: An interviewer would definitely take issue with the inconsistent base of the matrix (0- or 1-based). And the interviewer would probably prefer an answer that is more user-friendly (prompts, allowing commas) and robust (checking types, numbers of rows and columns).

Comment: i mean it's remote task. You need to do a some task to take a invite to interview, this is a example of task at previous years. It just part of task, i need to put values inside row and coloms to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for taking matrix input in python:

```
n,m=map(int,raw_input().split())
a=n*[m*[0]]
j=0
for i in range (0,n):
    a[i][j]=map(int,raw_input().split())
    j+=1
j=0
for i in range (0,n):
    print a[i][j]
    j+=1
```

Comment: When I run that code (the equivalent of it in Python 3), the printout looks nice but the actual result for `a` is `[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]`, which is not what was desired.